# Android Navigation Double Drawer with ActionBarDrawerToggle

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-toolbar, drawertoggle

I have implemented a double drawer layout. I have also set up an ActionBarDrawerToggle.

My problem is when I click on the home button, my left drawer opens and the animation is played. My right drawer when opened also shows the drawer opening animation. This causes strange sync issues with the Home Icon even when using mDrawerToggle.syncState();

What I am trying to do is intercept the home button click event that opens the left drawer so I can test which drawer is open, then close that one appropriately. Is there a way to set a click listener on the home icon? (The icon used with Android 5.0, and when mActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true); mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); are used)

I have tried checking onOptionsItemSelected for the "android.R.id.home" item, but it is never called when i click home to open the left drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Since `ActionBarDrawerToggle` just manages the home drawable the only reason you don't get the `onOptionItemSelected` callback is that you're inside a fragment.

`onOptionItemSelected` with `android.R.id.home` is only delivered inside an activity. This is because Action Bar is activity-scoped (at most one Action Bar per activity).

Override `onOptionItemSelected` inside the activity instead.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  int id = item.getItemId();
  switch (id) {
    case android.R.id.home:
      // Do something.
      return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```